# display a component by exporting in react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to lean react by solving a problem in react. Providing the react code challenge below. I am seeing the below error in browser. I googled but still no luck, not sure how to solve it. Providing my code below and stackblitz. Can you guys help me.

Property 'stateDropdown' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.(2339)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ngl4yu?description=React%20%20%20TypeScript%20starter%20project&file=src%2Fcomponents%2FstateDropdown.tsx,src%2Fcomponents%2FstateDropdown.css,src%2FApp.tsx&title=React%20Starter

```
import { FC } from 'react';

import './style.css';
import { stateDropdown } from './components/stateDropdown';

export const App: FC<{ name: string }> = ({ name }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <stateDropdown />
      <h1>Hello {name}!</h1>
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

coding challenge https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V2zEAXLQbF4&t=794s

Answer (score 0):

User-defined JSX components (such as `stateDropdown`) should be defined using PascalCase rather than camelCase in order to allow JSX to differentiate them from HTML elements (i.e. `<div>`, `<h1>`, `<p>`, etc.).

```
import { FC } from 'react';

import './style.css';
import { StateDropdown } from './components/StateDropdown';

export const App: FC<{ name: string }> = ({ name }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <StateDropdown />
      <h1>Hello {name}!</h1>
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```